# OpenShift: MySQL PDO 'connection refused', works locally

Tags: mysql, openshift-online-2, pdo, connection-refused

I have an API i want to deploy to OpenShift, everything works locally, but when trying to use it online i get some problems. When trying to connect to the database, using PDO, i get this error:

Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

i have the database set up correctly, and i have the correct details for the connection (im pretty sure). heres some code:

```
$username = "myuser"; 
$password = "lmnop"; 
$host = "127.0.0.1"; 
$dbname = "loginapi"; 
$port = "3306";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
```

what could be wrong that OpenShift is not allowing the connection? considering that this works on my local machine?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try each of these steps, clear cache, refresh and check

1. From `$host = "127.0.0.1";` change to `$host = "localhost";`
2. Check whether the default port is 3306 or anything else. Check the process name and port

   `netstat -tln`
3. Enable `skip-networking` (comment out # ) in my.cnf
4. Have a look in `/etc/hosts` as well to ensure everything is fine there
5. Also `--bind-address` if set to 127.0.0.1, the server accepts connections only on that address

Comment: Explanation is that mysql uses a unix socket for communication when using `localhost` but tries a network connection with the IP address. Often the mysql daemon doesn't listen on the network (via the `skip-networking` directive) for security reasons.